# JAVA- Bluecove InputStream communication

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am trying to send a continuous stream of data from a raspberry pi to another pi through bluetooth using java. For the same, I am using the bluecove2.1.0-snapshot.jar.
I have created a bluetooth server in the pi which is continuously sending the data and I have a bluetooth client in the other raspberry pi which is trying to receive the data. For this I am trying to use bluetooth serial port profile using RFCOMM. As soon both the raspberry pis are paired, the bluetooth server is sending the data through the InputStream. Now, the problem what I am facing is, during the continuous sending of data from the server, the raspberry pi which is supposed to receive it, is not at all able to receive anything. It can only receive the last sent data as soon as the bluetooth server releases the InputStream.

I believe this is due to the blocking InputStream which is returned by the pairing of the both devices. I couldn't find any solution to implement the same using non-blocking streams because Bluecove Library only has Api for blocking streams. This is the reason that the continuous delivery of the messages fails. I wanted to implement some functionality to simultaneously read and write messages from an InputStream.Could anyone help me please?

This is my server code:

```
    public final class SPPServer {

private static StreamConnection connection = null;

private static OutputStream outputStream = null;

private static StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = null;

private static PrintWriter writer = null;

private static void init() throws IOException {
    final UUID uuid = new UUID("0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB", false);
    final String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=Bluetooth-Milling-Machine-Simulation";

    streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) MicroeditionConnector.open(connectionString, Connector.WRITE,
            false);

    System.out.println("Milling Machine Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
    connection = streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

    final RemoteDevice device = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection);

    System.out.println("Remote device address: " + device.getBluetoothAddress());
    System.out.println("Remote device name: " + device.getFriendlyName(true));

    outputStream = connection.openOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
    System.out.println("Address: " + localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
    System.out.println("Name: " + localDevice.getFriendlyName());

    init();

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        sendResponse();
        try {
            writer.close();
            writer = null;
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private static void sendResponse() throws IOException {
    final String data = "A";
    System.out.println("Broadcasting data (" + data + ")");
    writer.write(data + "\r\n");
}
}
```

The following snippet is from the client.

```
    /**
 * Reading data from the stream
 */
private void doRead() {
    try {
        if (this.m_streamConnection != null) {
            this.m_inputStream = this.m_streamConnection.openInputStream();
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Input Stream: " + this.m_inputStream);
        if (this.m_inputStream != null) {
            this.m_bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.m_inputStream));
        }
        LOGGER.info("Buffered Reader: " + this.m_bufferedReader);

        /**
         * if (!this.m_bufferedReader.ready()) { throw new RuntimeException(
         * "Bluetooth Communication Problem (Buffer not ready)"); }
         **/
        if (this.m_bufferedReader != null) {
            LOGGER.info(
                    "Buffered Reader Lines List: " + this.m_bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            this.m_response = this.m_bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Bluetooth Data Received: " + this.m_response);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
    } finally {
        try {
            if ((this.m_inputStream != null) && (this.m_bufferedReader != null)) {
                this.m_inputStream.close();
                this.m_bufferedReader.close();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Error closing input stream");
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Used to establish connection between the paired bluetooth device and RPi
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    LOGGER.info("Bluetooth Connection initiating for ... " + s_serviceRecord.getHostDevice().getBluetoothAddress());

    final String connectionURL = s_serviceRecord.getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Connecting to..." + s_serviceRecord.getHostDevice().getBluetoothAddress()
                + " with connection url " + connectionURL);
        this.m_streamConnection = (StreamConnection) MicroeditionConnector.open(connectionURL, Connector.READ,
                false);
        LOGGER.info("Successfully Connected to " + s_serviceRecord.getHostDevice().getBluetoothAddress()
                + " with stream " + this.m_streamConnection);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Not able to connect to the remote device. " + Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
    }
    LOGGER.info("Connection Established with " + s_serviceRecord.getHostDevice().getBluetoothAddress());
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Getting IO Streams for " + s_serviceRecord.getHostDevice().getBluetoothAddress());
        this.doRead();

        LOGGER.debug(
                "Streams Returned-> InputStream: " + this.m_inputStream + " OutputStream: " + this.m_outputStream);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Unable to retrieve stream connection for remote device" + Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing the PrintWriter? Are you aware that closes the underlying stream? So trying to open a new one on the same stream and then trying to use it cannot work?

Comment: Thanks a lot EJP for the answer. 
As I have mentioned before that, while the Bluetooth Server is using the Stream Connection, any other client who needs to use the stream to read the data simultaneously, is blocked by the Bluetooth Server. I tried to close the Printwriter to release the stream, acquired by the Server so that the bluetooth client can read the data. But it also didn't work.  The connection though is not closed as I haven't opened another Output Stream from the Stream Connection. I need to read and write to the stream simultaneously but couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Let's be accurate here. You *thought* you had to do it, but you were mistaken. If it didn't work, you didn't have to do it. It was just another bug.